# Is there a naming convention for method that returns completely a brand new object?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, naming, method-names

Is there a naming convention for method that returns completely a brand new object?

"Generate" ?  "Create" ?

Comment: and, finally, what is the difference between "brand new object", "new object", and just "object"?

Comment: you should reformulate your question, but not downvote the direct answer.

Answer (score 3):

It can be `Create` as @David suggested, or `GetNew` - like GetNewProduct().
I prefer GetNew, because *Create* is more used in factory methods, *GetSomething* for plain objects, and then *GetNewSomething* to emphasize that actually a new object is being created.

Comment: I really like the idea and the distinction between Create and GetNew prefixes.

Comment: if a function returns a new object, isn't that a factory? I'm struggling to see the distinction.

Comment: Not exactly - a factory (as dictated by the design pattern) is supposed to serve a one of various objects, all inherit from the same class or implement a specific interface. The factory method is responsible to give you a concrete class implementation given certain business rules or parameters you pass to the factory method.  GetNew is like Get but with the difference that a new (one specific known) object is returned.

Comment: I must say I struggle to understand the need for Get in all this. That makes the function name a verb which I feel should be reserves for methods with void return. I'd prefer to strip the Get and make the name a noun since it returns something.

Answer (score 0):

Bar bar Foo.barFactory();   is often one used.
if Bar is an interface, the exact Bar can be picked by Foo's barFactory,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score -1):

There is any public Microsoft recommended convention for that.

Comment: If you (as written) mean "is", then perhaps cite it? or did you mean "isn't"?

Comment: @Marc: "There is *any* ... convention" ;)